# Parallel Processes Results Written To Single File

Tags: linux, file, process

I am new to Linux and was introduced to the "&" recently.  I have to run several traceroutes and store them in a single file, and I am curious if I am able to kick off these traceroutes in parallel?

I tried the following but the results in the generated file, are not kept apart?  Well, that is what it seems to me.

```
traceroute  -n -z 100 www.yahoo.com >> theLog.log &
traceroute  -n -z 100 www.abc.com >> theLog.log &
```

Is what I am asking even possible to do?  If so what commands should I be using?

Thanks for any direction given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following command they are not really in parallel, but you can continue using your terminal, and the results are taken apart:

```
{ traceroute -n -z 100 www.yahoo.com; traceroute -n -z 100 www.abc.com; } >> theLog.log &
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  On my system, I had to use "()" instead of "{}".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could investigate [parallel](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parallel) (and tell us about your experience)?
If you are on Ubuntu, you can do `sudo apt-get install moreutils` to obtain `parallel`.

Comment: It is funny that this didn't come up in my search.  Yes, I am using Ubuntu and only came across the "xargs".  After looking at that command, it seemed as a dead end.

Comment: @PED: `parallel` promises to do exactly what you've asked. Example from README: `parallel traceroute ::: foss.org.my gnu.org freenetproject.org`. See `--group` option (enabled by default) http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parallel

Comment: `xargs` is used to construct argument lists and feed them to commands.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to run parallel is better to keep the intermediary results in separated files them join them at the end. The steps would be to start each trace to it's log file and store their pid, wait for them all to stop, them join the results, something like the following:

```
traceroute  -n -z 100 www.yahoo.com > theLog.1.log & PID1=$!
traceroute  -n -z 100 www.abc.com > theLog.2.log & PID2=$!    
wait $PDI1 $PDI2    
cat theLog.1.log theLog.2.log > theLog.log
rm theLog.2.log theLog.1.log
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have it written, the behavior is undefined.  You might try what enzotib posted, or try to have each write to their own file and cat them together at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`traceroute`s in the [@enzotib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965141/parallel-processes-results-written-to-single-file/3965155#3965155) are executed one at a time in sequence.

You can execute `traceroute`s in parallel using suggested by [@rmk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965141/parallel-processes-results-written-to-single-file/3965167#3965167) the [`parallel` utility](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parallel).

```
$ /usr/bin/time parallel traceroute -n -z 100 <hosts.txt >> parallel.log
24.78user 0.63system 1:24.04elapsed 30%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 37456maxresident)k
72inputs+72outputs (2major+28776minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Sequential analog is 5 times slower:

```
$ /usr/bin/time ./sequential.sh 
24.63user 0.51system 7:19.09elapsed 5%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5296maxresident)k
112inputs+568outputs (1major+8759minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Where `sequential.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
( while read host; do traceroute -n -z 100 $host; done; ) <hosts.txt >>sequential.log
```

And `hosts.txt` is:

```
www.yahoo.com
www.abc.com
www.google.com
stackoverflow.com
facebook.com
youtube.com
live.com
baidu.com
wikipedia.org
blogspot.com
qq.com
twitter.com
msn.com
yahoo.co.jp
taobao.com
google.co.in
sina.com.cn
amazon.com
google.de
google.com.hk
```